# DateTime on Where Clause Oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime

it seems there are lot of query syntax to fetch data on oracle database, here I just want to ask about the query that works fine but I cant understand at all. The query is :

```
Select
....
From
...
Where
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') +
(create_date  / ( 60 * 60 * 24 )),
'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS') = '06/30/14 21:41:11'
;
```

From the query above it's work fine. But I cant understand why there's **TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS** and **(create_date  / ( 60 * 60 * 24 )),
    'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS')**

on the *create_date* fields it show unix datetime such as 1404164471

Can anybody explain about this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` converts a string (first argument) in certain format (second argument) to a date.

`(create_date  / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ))` **create_date** contains seconds, this expression converts them into the number of days (1 minute = 60 seconds, 1 hour = 60 minutes, 1 day = 24 hours => 60*60*24 = the number of seconds in a day). When you add a number to a date Oracle thinks that this number contains days that's why you need such a conversation.

`TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + (create_date  / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ))` gives you a date stored in create_date but in "traditional" format

It seems you need to compare unix time with date. It would be better to use this condition:

```
Select
....
From
...
Where create_date = trunc( (TO_DATE('06/30/14 21:41:11', 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS') 
                          - TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                           ) * 24 * 60 * 60
                         );
```

Comment: I got it, so this TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') query used for define the first default time that readable by machine then I have to add it by the days of the create_date field to calculate length from the first default time to selected date then convert it to a proper date format?

Comment: @Rezaakhmadg Yes, but you don't need this: "then convert it to a date". When you add days to a date you receive a date so you don't need to convert it again

Comment: why I should adding this query TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') by a day in create_date field?

Comment: @Rezaakhmadg From your WHERE clause it seems that you need to compare create_date in unix time with some ordinary date. In this case you have two options: 1) convert unix time to an ordinary date format; 2) convert an ordinary date to a unix time. You did the first.

Comment: @Rezaakhmadg Unix time is a number of seconds since January 1 1970 that's why you get January 1 1970 and add create_date expressed in dayy to it.

Comment: @Rezaakhmadg I gave you an example where you can convert a date to a unix time. It's better because you don't apply any functions on your column and an index (if any) can be used

Comment: So, if I adding a date with an integer, the integer read as a day? thats why the create fild have to divided by a day. Ok thank you for ur answer

Comment: @Rezaakhmadg Yes, but not only integer - you may add any number. For example: "sysdate + 1/24/60/60" adds one second to the current date (1/24/60/60 is not integer)

Answer (score 1):

The outer to_char(,) creates a string from the calculated date. This is so that it can be compared with the string '06/30/14 21:41:11'.

Inside the to_char some calculation is going on, the addition of to date values.

```
TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
+ (create_date  / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ))
```

The to_date function takes a date value in string format ('01/01/1970 00:00:00'), and a format string ('MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') to tell it how to interpret the date value.

create_date seems to be a number in seconds 9probably since 01-01-1970). It is devided by the number of seconds in a day so that will result in a number of days. So what you get is the create date in real calendar value.

Comment: So if I want to convert string to date format, I should put TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') first? and it is necessary for this code + (create_date  / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ))? the first code convert to date and the second code it's integer value , what for add operator on this two code

Comment: The addition takes place inside the to_char( <addition> , <format)